# implement unhandled exception Capture event in window service C#?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am New in C# I want to **capture unhanded exception in Windows services.** whey i try this window services crash i don't what's problem...
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about showing us some code providing us with at least the most tiny bit of information about what you're doing?

Comment: check in eventviewere of windows this could help you why window service is crashed. and also pass some code snippts here this would help you to get answer quiker

Comment: if i never got any answer how can i approve answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

add this in Constructor

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

after Constructor

```
  void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex =(Exception)e.ExceptionObject;

       ....
    }
```